# Add cell values up to a constant

Tags: excel, vba

We are shipping a consignment. I have product name in column 1 and respective units to pack in column 2 of excel. I want to bunch products in groups of 32. Once the sum of units reach 32 two new rows are added first of which is blank and the second is the same as the last row with the remaining units.

```
product1    12
product2    16
product3     8
product4     9
```

to look like

```
product1    12
product2    16
product3     4
(empty row)
product3     4
product4     9
```

and so on.

---

Please suggest a solution.

Comment: Welcome to SO. If you have an `excel-vba` tag, if you don't post **the code you have tried** the question is apt to get downvoted and closed. For more help, show us your attempt and what is not working with it. See [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am going to post mine:

```
Sub nnnn()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim ttl As Integer
    Dim i As Long
    Dim temp As Integer

    i = 1

    Set ws = ActiveSheet 'This can be changed to Set ws = Sheets("Sheet1")
    With ws
        'Loop until the end of the range dynamically
        Do Until .Cells(i, 1) = ""
            'check if less than 32
            If ttl + .Cells(i, 2) < 32 Then
                ttl = ttl + .Cells(i, 2)
                i = i + 1
            ' check if equal to 32
            ElseIf ttl + .Cells(i, 2) = 32 Then
                Rows(i + 1).Insert
                i = i + 2
                ttl = 0
            'if not less than or equal must be over
            Else
                Rows(i + 1 & ":" & i + 2).Insert                       
                temp = .Cells(i, 2)
                .Cells(i, 2) = 32 - ttl
                .Cells(i + 2, 1) = .Cells(i, 1)
                .Cells(i + 2, 2) = temp - .Cells(i, 2)
                i = i + 2
                ttl = 0
            End If
        Loop
    End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should work:

```
Sub Consignment()

    Dim Rng As Range
    Dim Cell As Range
    Dim GroupTotal As Integer

    Set Rng = Sheet1.Range("B1:B60") '<-- Set to your units to pack column

    For Each Cell In Rng

        GroupTotal = GroupTotal + CInt(Cell.Value)

        If (GroupTotal = 32) Then

            'Insert just one row, no products to be split:
            Cell.Offset(1, -1).EntireRow.Insert

            'Reset Group Total:
            GroupTotal = 0

        ElseIf (GroupTotal > 32) Then

            'The amount in which we divide the product to ensure the unit total equals 32
            Dim SplitProduct As Integer: SplitProduct = GroupTotal - 32

            'The name of the product we want to split between two groups.
            Dim CurrentProduct As String: CurrentProduct = Cell.Offset(0, -1).Value

            'Insert two rows, the second one we will include the name of the split group and remaining units
            Cell.Offset(1, 0).EntireRow.Insert
            Cell.Offset(1, 0).EntireRow.Insert

            'Add split product to new group
            Cell.Offset(2, -1).Value = CurrentProduct
            'Add remaing product to new group
            Cell.Offset(2, 0).Value = SplitProduct
            'Remove product from group to leave 32 products in total
            Cell.Value = CInt(Cell.Value) - SplitProduct

            'Reset Group Total:
            GroupTotal = 0

        End If

    Next Cell

End Sub
```

**Note** My answer uses the `Offset` function to grab the Product name so when we split any amount we can duplicate this in the rows beneath.

Comment: This is definitely close but, If you look at the example it splits product 3 between the first and second.  Each group must equal 32 and the remaining gets moved to the next group.

Comment: this doesn't quite meet the needs the requirements. It will not leave the proper item counts next to the product name

Comment: Yes I just realised this! I am quickly refining my answer :-)

Comment: @ScottHoltzman updated my answer!